# Trying to stop a loop with an event, but it doesn't

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

from what I know about `asyncio` this should only print 0 to 4, but it goes through the full 10 digits.

Shouldn't the `stop_loop` coroutine stop awaiting the event and cancel the loop after i hits 5?

```
import asyncio

async def run():
    for i in range(10):
        if i == 5:
            e.set()
        print(i)

async def stop_loop():
    await e.wait()
    l.stop()

e = asyncio.Event()

l = asyncio.get_event_loop()
l.set_debug(True)

l.create_task(stop_loop())
l.create_task(run())

try:
    l.run_forever()
finally:
    l.close()
```

Output is

```
machine:programs user$ python3 conditional_stop.py 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asyncio` works by switching between tasks that are implemented as *coroutines*. A coroutine is a **cooperative** routine, in that coroutines *voluntarily* give up control once in a while, to *let* the `asyncio` event loop switch to another task. This is different from threading, where each task can and will be interrupted 'at will' by the scheduler.

And coroutines give up control every time they use `await` on another coroutine, usually at points where some I/O is involved. I/O is slow, and the `asyncio` event loop takes responsibility of monitoring for changes in I/O streams so it can know what tasks are ready to do more work again.

Your problem is that you have a coroutine that is not cooperating:

```
async def run():
    for i in range(10):
        if i == 5:
            e.set()
        print(i)
```

That routine has no `await` statements, so it never gives up control to the event loop. No other coroutines can be run.

You could await on a `asyncio.sleep()` call:

```
async def run():
    for i in range(10):
        if i == 5:
            e.set()
        print(i)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.01)  # wait 1/100th of a second
```

Another option would be to replace the `print(i)` call (which is an I/O operation) with one that uses a non-blocking output stream. If you are not on Windows, then you can create a `StreamWriter` asynchronous I/O wrapper for `sys.stdout`:

```
import os
import sys

async def run():
    # create an async writer for sys.stdout
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    writer_transport, writer_protocol = await loop.connect_write_pipe(
        asyncio.streams.FlowControlMixin, os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'wb'))
    writer = asyncio.streams.StreamWriter(
        writer_transport, writer_protocol, None, loop)

    for i in range(10):
        if i == 5:
            e.set()
        writer.write(b'%d\n' % i)
        await writer.drain()
```

Unfortunately, there is no support yet for creating async I/O streams for the Windows console streams, see [Pyton issue #26832](https://bugs.python.org/issue26832), you'd have to use a threadpool executor instead.

Note that even with the latter coroutine, there is *no guarantee* that the `stop` coroutine will actually be run soon enough after `e.set()` is called to cancel `run()` before it reads 10! The loop is free to give control right back to the same coroutine after `await writer.drain()` has been handled.  Writing short lines to the `sys.stdout` stream buffer is fast, and the only thing `.drain()` does is just give the writing coroutines time to flush the internal transport buffer; with direct non-blocking writes to `sys.stdout` succeeding most of the time that's not always enough room for `stop_loop()` to jump in and the `run()` coroutine will have written all its lines to the writer transport .